# NoClassDefFoundError resolved by renaming the JAR file

Tags: java, jar

I have a large java application running on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux server.  This application has around 100 jars.  On most RHEL systems the application runs fine, however, on certain RHEL systems (all RHEL versions are the same) I get a NoClassDefFoundError on startup (before my application gets a chance to do anything).  If I rename the JAR file which contains the class (e.g. com-test-1.3.4.jar -> com-test-1.3.4-2.jar) everything starts up great even though the renameing doesn't change the order of the JAR in my directory listing.  If I add the JAR file to the beginning of the classpath it works great.  On other systems with the exact same OS/classpath/java/jars it works great. If I try to run the class that java says is missing (before renaming), java reports that the class does not have a main method so I know the class itself is loadable/findable.  I have tried the latest version of Java 1.7 with no luck.  The classpath is specified using the wildcard operator (e.g. CLASSPATH=/home/test/*).

The actual exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/testpath/TestClass
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.testpath.TestClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your classpath on a failing system?

Comment: export CLASSPATH=:/home/user/myapp/*:/home/user/myapp/:/home/user/otherapp/*:/home/user/otherapp2/*

Comment: Is it possible that there are different copies or versions of the same JAR in multiple places in your classpath?

Comment: I looked for that and did not find an instance where that was the case.  But if it *was* the case I feel like I would get a different error, not a class not found error.

Comment: Usually, yeah.  Just brainstorming.  Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Oracle JDK 1.7.0_51 (we tried the latest version of 1.7 and it had the same problem).

Comment: Are you able to load other classes from the same jar?